# Making sure Serializable object always with latest data - c#

Tags: c#, serialization

I am writing a program that works all the time in the background of windows,
the data is collected all the time and saved in an serializable object in a file.

When starting the program I get all the data that has been collected and saved in a file from last usage(the serializable object) and restore it to the program.

**I want to make sure that all the time if the user close the program and start it again, all latest data has been serializable and saved into the file and no data has been lost**

I thought of overriding the method - static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e) and there to serialize the object when the user close the program - but that way arose few problems...

**what do you think is the best way achieving this goal?**

Thank you
Yuval

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I'd use lightweight database like SQLite for this purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you rely only on events (mouse move, key pressed, program closing) - this is pretty much all you can do. You can't guarantee that everything will be alright if power turn off for example. Your app forcebly closed - you lose everything in memory.

Other way around, you can serialize it once in a while (every few seconds). In separate thread for example, this way you only need to make sure file is not corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, is it a good practice to serialize so many times? like every second or so..

Comment: If you do this good - it is. For example, you can store some kind of hash-sum, and compute it before any serialization, then compare with previous version from file. On the other hand if your model changes too frequent the best choise will be to extend time interval between serializations. This is not perfect solution, but user not perfect either.